# How to troubleshoot hanging /POST request with a body to Express

Tags: express, http-headers, http-post

I'm hoping someone can point me in the right direction. I'm using `http` to send a request to express and the request just hangs, it'll return a 500 Internal Server Error if I restart my express server, or restart the client with "request aborted". The odd thing is it seems to only be when I submit a /POST request with a body - but a POST request with no body works ok.

This is my request:

```js
const the_Headers = {
  Authorization: "Bearer <token>",
  "x-custom-header": "custom-header-val",
  "content-type": "application/json",
  "content-length": "21",
}
const data = "{\"test\":\"123\"}"
const result = await new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
  const request = http.request(
    new URL("http://localhost/some/path"), 
    {headers: the_Headers, method: POST}, 
    (res) => {
      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let responseBody = '';

      res.on('data', (chunk) => {
        responseBody += chunk;
      });

      res.on('end', () => {
        resolve({body: responseBody});
      });
    });
    request.on('error', (err) => {
      reject({statusCode: 500, error: err});
    });

    if (data)
      request.write(data);
    
    request.end();
  })
});
```

This is my router:

```js
router.post("/some/path",    
    async (req, res) => {
        //  makes it to this breakpoint with empty(no body) POST request
        res.status(200)
            .json({ message: "body is: " + req.body.toString()});
})
```

This is the output with `DEBUG=express:*`

```sh
express:router dispatching POST /some/path +7s
express:router query  : /some/path +1ms
express:router expressInit  : /some/path +0ms
express:router urlencodedParser  : /some/path +0ms
express:router jsonParser  : /some/path +1ms
... (does not proceed from here - so assuming problem with jsonParser)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a content-length mismatch.

Header was passing a length of 21 - when data was 14. This resulted in the readstream within jsonParser to never call the end() method.

Comment: Thank you! It's fascinating how we end up with the same issue, in different scenarios. Lesson learned. When dealing with multiple concurrent and parallel calls. Make sure that you provide the proper configuration. Configuration mismatch deprives your sleep.